# How to use sticky header with segmented control in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, sticky

I have a layout in which I make a sticky header with segmented control and there would be a collapsible header just above the segmented control. So I m confused about what would be the best approach to implement it, whether table view or scroll view & how would I achieve this. If anybody has some idea or reference please help me out.

Image when not scrolled
[image]

Image when scrolled

[image]

Comment: "a sticky header for segmented control"?

Comment: actually tab bar would be sticky

Answer (score 0):

Since the content you use is scrollable you should do this using some form of scroll view. There are few ways you can do this:

- Add views directly on scroll view
- Use vertical stack view to layout views on scroll view
- Use `UITableView` (is a subclass of scroll view)
- Use `UICollectionView` (is a subclass of scroll view)

In any case you should assign a `delegate` to a scroll view that you use. By doing that you may track changes in scroll view offset by implementing an optional protocol method `scrollViewDidScroll`. Depending on the scroll view content offset you may choose to collapse or extend your header.

The header itself could be on scroll view but I suggest that you rather put it above it. You could simply constrain it to top and have a full priority height to be equal or greater than the height of your segment control. Then have another low-priority height constraint (a priority of 900 should do) which can be dragged as an outlet to your code. There are multiple ways of achieving this and doing it this way should produce a code similar to

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    headerMaximumHeightConstraint?.constant = collapsableHeaderMaximumHeight-scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

This will make your header extend as user drags downwards and collapse dragging upwards. Since this constraint has a lower priority than the one with height-greater-than-minimum-height the header will not collapse more than that.

What is contained within the header and how that is collapsed, animated is completely up to you. You could have 2 views where the bottom one has your segment control. I would not shrink the two views but rather let the top one slide off the screen. Perhaps you could decrease alpha on it when that happens so that it nicely hides away.

As for your scroll view you will need a bit of spacing at the top. This may be achieved by placing empty space at the top (with table view or collection view that means placing an empty/invisible cell, header or section at the top). Or another approach is to play around with content insets which is also a property of a scroll view.

There are other typical aspects when having collapsable header which you did not specify in your question. On of such is that if user stops scrolling while header is half-collapsed then you should either animate it to fully collapsed or fully extended. To do so you need to play around with 2 more delegate methods:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if decelerate == false {
        snapHeader()
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    snapHeader()
}
```

Basically when user stops scrolling the scroll view may stop instantly or it will continue scrolling for a bit and then stop. Conveniently the two methods can be used like this to detect when the scrollview indeed did stop and you can snap your header at that point. Snapping of a header should then be something like this (again may vary depending on how exactly you implement your code).

```
private func snapHeader() {
    guard let headerMaximumHeightConstraint = headerMaximumHeightConstraint, let scrollView = self.tableView else { return }
    if headerMaximumHeightConstraint.constant > collapsableHeaderMaximumHeight*0.5 {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(.init(x: 0.0, y: collapsableHeaderMaximumHeight), animated: true)
    } else {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(.init(x: 0.0, y: collapsableHeaderMinimumHeight), animated: true)
    }
}
```

only the scroll view content offset should be corrected. The delegate methods should be able to apply the rest.

I hope this is enough to get you on the right track. If you find yourself stuck on some more specific problem please ask a more specific question.